# How to fix broken Windows user profile after latest Win10 pro upgrade?

Tags: windows-10

After rebooting for upgrades on Saturday 2017-10-14, many or perhaps all Windows Store -installed apps stopped working on my win10 pro computer. They all show an error dialog similar to this one, from Edge's 1Password addon:

[image]

The English form of the localized error message is

> The specified user does not have a valid profile.

Can't really find anything on Google about anybody having this specific issue, there are some articles about fixing broken profiles but those instances talk about being unable to log in. I have no such issue. Apart from these Store app problems, the only other symptom is that I am unable to set Edge as my default browser. Instead of Edge, the browser selector in the settings app shows an entry labeled "Launch Windows App" with an Edge icon, but then links just don't work. Reinstalling Store apps does not fix the problem.

Edited to add: The latest updates installed on the machine seem to be "2017-10 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1703 for x64-based Systems (KB4041676)" and "Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool for Windows 8, 8.1, 10 and Windows Server 2012, 2012 R2, 2016 x64 Edition - October 2017 (KB890830)".

Comment: Which update specifically are you talking about

Comment: @Ramhound probably "2017-10 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1703 for x64-based Systems (KB4041676)" and "Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool for Windows 8, 8.1, 10 and Windows Server 2012, 2012 R2, 2016 x64 Edition - October 2017 (KB890830)", they both show up as having been installed 2017-10-11, but I guess I just took three days to reboot.

Comment: If you remove those updates does everything does the behavior stop exhibiting itself?

Comment: Good question, I didn't even realize that was an option. I'll try to uninstall them and see if that gets me anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

For people hitting this page because suffering of the same problem, **rebooting one more time after updates** could fix the issue.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @brunovam unfortunately, it should be the accepted answer